# Choosing only one each node from XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

I've got an XML file and have to transform it to another XML file. 
I have no idea what I should do to choose only once each node to the second file
(with all that this node contains!)

> < aaa > ... < /aaa >
>
> < bbb > ... < /bbb >
>
> < ccc > ... < /ccc >
>
> < aaa > ... < /aaa >
>
> < bbb > ... < /bbb >`

and so on.
I would like to copy only first of < aaa >, < bbb >.
What sholud I write in XML file?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a grouping question. Group the items by their name and copy the first item in each group.

Given a well-formed input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <aaa>aaa1</aaa>
    <bbb>bbb1</bbb>
    <ccc>ccc1</ccc>
    <aaa>aaa2</aaa>
    <bbb>bbb2</bbb>`
    <ccc>ccc3</ccc>
    <aaa>aaa3</aaa>
    <bbb>bbb3</bbb>`
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name()">
            <!-- Within the sequence constructor contained in the xsl:for-each-group element, the context item is the initial item of the relevant group. -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <aaa>aaa1</aaa>
   <bbb>bbb1</bbb>
   <ccc>ccc1</ccc>
</root>
```